# Make windows 10 use the dhcp6-address it have, not autogenerated

Tags: dhcp, ipv6

A window 10 machine gets its ipv6 address from dhcp6, and it also have an adress based on mac

```
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:exam:ple:12::fffe:a15e(Preferred)
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 18. november 2021 01:49:31
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 18. november 2021 03:26:39
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:exam:ple:12:f279:59ff:xxxx:892a(Preferred)
```

To make logging easier, I want it to use the address given by dhcp6, not the autogenerated.
But both dhcp6-address and slaac-addreess are (Preferred)
How do I "unprefer" the slaac-address?

Comment: You will have to provide information on the network card.  There is likely a setting that enables/disables this functionality within the properties of the card.

Comment: I would think this was up in the layer provided by windows, not in the low level of the driver.

Comment: My network adapter only has a single IPv6 address